# Why {{}} is syntax error while [[]] isn't?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand what's wrong with `{{}}` while `[[]]` works.

```
#works fine
a = []
a = [[]]

h = {}
h = {{}} #throws syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
```

Comment: you really should think about that `=>` error.. usually compilers **are** helpful in what they tell you!

Comment: Why is this so heavily downvoted?

Comment: @R.T.: probably because the OP has no clue and can't be bothered to read the error message.

Comment: The question here is when an array can hold a blank array and when a blank hash is valid, why a hash of blank hash invalid.

Comment: because hash HAS TO consist of key and value. and in your example you do not fulfil this it.

Comment: @andreydeineko: if that is so, how is it that `{}` is valid

Comment: "and when a blank hash is valid, why a hash of blank hash invalid" - because hash of blank hash is not a blank hash itself. It contains something which is not a key-value pair (thus it's invalid)

Comment: @Bala you create a hash by providing zero or more key-value *pairs*. `{{}}` doesn't contain a pair, just a single value; it's like `{1}`

Comment: @Stefan: That makes sense now. Just tried `{{}=>{}}`. Please could you post it as an answer unless you don't want to be seen having answered a heavily down voted question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a hash by providing zero or more key-value pairs.

- `{}` creates a hash with a zero key-value pairs, i.e. an empty hash
- `{'foo' => 'bar'}` creates a hash with a single pair (key `'foo'` and value `'bar'`)
- `{'foo'}` raises a `SyntaxError` because there's only a key, the value is missing

The error message says the same: `unexpected '}', expecting =>`, i.e. Ruby expects a `=>` after `'foo'`, not a closing `}`.

`{{}}` raises the same `SyntaxError` because the value is missing. The hash equivalent  to `[[]]` would probably look like this:

```
{{}=>{}}
```

Comment: Useful reading: [Ruby Grammar (BNF rules)](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/cse305/RubyBNF.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Because `[[]]` is array of arrays, while `{{}}` is meaningless garbage.

Comment: To be precise, it is an array containing one empty array.

Comment: @Jerska: certainly. But "array of one empty array" doesn't sound as well to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Because an hash contains a mapping between a key and a value, when an array contains only a list of values.

Consider `{}` an hash. In itself, it only is a value.
So you could definitely do :

```
{ a: {} }
```

But

```
{ {} }
```

in itself is not enough.

Also note that

```
[ {} ]
```

obviously works.

Comment: this is the ONLY answer, and none of others makes sense.

Comment: @andreydeineko: true dat.

Answer (score 0):

An array needs only value as the member.
So, in the case of this:

```
a = [[]]
```

the member is `[]` which is an empty array.
On the other hand, a hash needs a key and a value to make a member.
So, the formula for making a hash is:

```
h = { a key => a value, ...}
```

Each member of a hash is separated by comma.
Therefore if you want to make a valid hash that contains an empty hash inside it.
You can choose one of these:

```
h = { :key => {} }
```

or

```
h = { {} => :value }
```